# jQuery Object Filled Or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if a jQuery Object contains a value or not.

```
var objContactList = new Object();
objContacList.Address = "xyz abc";
objContactList.Email = "abc@abc.com";
objContactList.MobileNo = "9013027233";
```

now, I want to check if `ObjContactList.Address` and `objContactList.MobileNo` is filled or not. For this I did this:

```
$.each(objContactList, function(i, val) {
    if (objContactList[i].val() == '') {
        // do this 
    }
})
```

Comment: What you have is a POJS object - nothing to do with jQuery at all. Also, do you have a problem with your code?

Comment: its an object how u will use each

Comment: yes this not working

Comment: `.val()` is troubling you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Its working

```js
   var objContactList = new Object();
    objContactList.Address = "xyz abc";
    objContactList.Email = "abc@abc.com";
    objContactList.MobileNo = "9013027233";
    objContactList.pin = "";
    

for(var propertyName in objContactList) {
  if(objContactList.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)){
    var value = objContactList[propertyName]
    if(value == ""){
    console.log(propertyName + " has no value");
    }
    else{
    console.log(propertyName + " has value");
    }
      }
    
    
}
```

Comment: i have more than 30 objects how can i do this for each
if(objContactList.hasOwnProperty("Email")){
    alert("success");
}
if(objContactList.hasOwnProperty("Address")){
    alert("success");
}

Comment: Made one more changes , check now

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are creating using object so using each u can not iterate so better u can check using two ways

**1 Way**

```
var objContactList = new Object();
objContactList.Address = "xyz abc";
objContactList.Email = "abc@abc.com";
objContactList.MobileNo = "9013027233";

if(objContactList.hasOwnProperty("Address ")){
    alert("Address is there");
}
if(objContactList.hasOwnProperty("Email")){
    alert("email is there");
}
```

2way

```
var objContactList = new Object();
    objContactList.Address = "xyz abc";
    objContactList.Email = "abc@abc.com";
    objContactList.MobileNo = "9013027233";

    if(objContactList.Address != "" || objContactList.Address != undefined){
        alert("Address is there");
    }
```

if u have more objects then Push to array

**JS**

```
var myarray = [];

var objContactList = new Object();
objContactList.Address = "xyz abc";
objContactList.Email = "abc@abc.com";
objContactList.MobileNo = "9013027233";

myarray.push(objContactList);
var objContactList2 = new Object();
objContactList2.Address = "xyz abc";
objContactList2.Email = "abc@abc.com";
objContactList2.MobileNo = "9013027233";

myarray.push(objContactList2);

for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    if (myarray[i].Address != "") {
        alert("Address is there");
    }
}
```

1 way to check the object is exist 2 way to check the value exist

Comment: how can i do this for each member in ObjContactList, i have more than 30 members in ObjContactList

Comment: u have to puch the entire 30 ojects in to array

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var objContactList = new Object();
        objContactList.Address = "xyz abc";
        objContactList.Email = "abc@abc.com";
        objContactList.MobileNo = "9013027233";

        if (objContactList.hasOwnProperty('Address')) {
            if (objContactList.Address != "") {
                alert('Address is : ' + objContactList.Address);
            } else {
                alert(' Address is empty');
            }
        }
         if (objContactList.hasOwnProperty('Email')) {
            if (objContactList.Email != "") {
                alert('Email is : ' + objContactList.Email);
            } else {
                alert(' Email is empty');
            }
        }
         if (objContactList.hasOwnProperty('MobileNo')) {
            if (objContactList.MobileNo != "") {
                alert('MobileNo is : ' + objContactList.MobileNo);
            } else {
                alert(' MobileNo is empty');
            }
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8apatfy6/